# Splitting and shifting a multipolygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm working with datasets that contain sets of vertices from -180 to +180 longitude, which jump back down to -180 after passing through +180. I need to string these sets together to form a (multi)polygon (which is pretty simple) that is only represented between -180 and +180. Right now, the jump from +180 to -180 creates ugly artifacts as the vertices get connected.

My current implementation is to use `ST_MakeLine` and `ST_MakePolygon` to string together the vertices, which I can do no problem. During this process, if the vertices cross +180, I shift them by +360 to keep the polygon in one piece, then split it into a multipolygon at +180.

This works fine, but I need a way to re-shift the polygon that lies to the right of +180 back down to -180, as this is what's required by the frontend.

Unfortunately, I'm working with a certain organization that does *not* like internal details to be shared, so I can't provide any specifics or images. I hope that isn't a problem.

Thank you!